# shortcut key for closing single tab in browser without using mouse

Tags: google-chrome

I was not able to search on google how to close single tab on browser . I was using chrome as well as mozilla suddenly my mouse broken now I want to close my unwanted automatic generated webpage.How can i close it.
I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Linux [Chrome Shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/linux/Chrome.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL + W will kill the current tab.  CTRL + 1/2/3/4/... will select the respective tab.